# Keycloak Creates new realm with default roles "uma_authorization" and "offline_access". I don't want these roles to be created

Tags: keycloak

I am trying to create new realm using JSON import option and it is creating realm with

```
"defaultRoles": [
"uma_authorization",
"offline_access"
],
```

I have written my script `"defaultRoles": []` but still it is creating these two default roles.May I know how can I create new realm without these two roles?
Suggest me something which I can automate going forward.

Answer (score 1):

Those are default roles, you should remove them from inside KC admin, Roles - Default Roles.